# Unique Database for each Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I need a live demo for a product. Said product uses ASP.NET with Entity Framework.

Currently I create a new in-memory database like this:

```cs
var sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
sqliteConnection.Open();

builder.Services
       .AddDbContextFactory<DatabaseContext>
           (options => options.UseSqlite(sqliteConnection,
                                         o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)));
```

However, I need this `DbContext` to be created for each session ("scoped"), so the live demo of our product always starts with the exact same data, for each session and they do not interfere with each other.

Comment: Anything you tried? It's very unclear what you're actually asking. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a session state.

To activate session state use:
See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
    builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

    app.UseSession();
```

Than you can add a kind of DataBase Connection Service like

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseService>(provider => new DataBaseService());
```

Code for the Service

```
public interface IDatabaseService {
    SqliteConnection GetConnection(string sessionID);
}

public class DataBaseService : IDatabaseService {
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    private Dictionary<string, MyConnection>  _connections = new();
    private readonly object _connectionsLock = new ();

    public DataBaseService(IServiceProvider provider) {
        _provider = provider;
        Task.Run(() => RemoveOutdatedSessions());
    }

    private void RemoveOutdatedSessions() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                lock (_connectionsLock) {
                    var date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);
                    foreach (var connection in _connections.Where(i => i.Value.LastUsed < date).ToList()) {
                        //TODO may be close the connection or ...???
                        _connections.Remove(connection.Key);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //Ignore Exceptions - make sure this runs forever...
            }
        }
    }

    public SqliteConnection GetConnection(string sessionID) {
        lock (_connectionsLock) {
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(sessionID, out var myConnection)) {
                myConnection.LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
                return myConnection.SqliteConnection;
            }
            _connections[sessionID] = new MyConnection();
            return _connections[sessionID].SqliteConnection;
        }
    }
}

public class MyConnection {
    public MyConnection() {
        SqliteConnection = new SqlliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public SqliteConnection SqliteConnection { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUsed { get; set; }
}
```

And you use it e.g. on a MVC Page like:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IDatabaseService _databaseService;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IDatabaseService databaseService) {
        _logger = logger;
        _databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    public void OnGet() {
        var con = _databaseService.GetConnection(HttpContext.Session.Id);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! This sounds exactly what I need. Also this looks very clean. I just tried to implement it and one thing I don't know exactly on how to achieve is, how to cleanup unused sessions. Sessions expire after the IdleTimeout ran out, but there is no mechanism on how to notify the server of a closed/inactive session. Is a timestamp which stores the creation datetime and removing all sessions, which are "older" than e.g. 2 hours, a valid thing to do in this situation? E.g. `private Dictionary<string, (SqliteConnection Connection, DateTime CreationDate)> _connections = new();`

Answer (score 0):

When using dependency injection in dotnet you have three lifetimes available for your services:

`Transient`: Services are created each time they're requested from the service container.

`Singleton`: Each request of the service implementation from the dependency injection container uses the same instance.

`Scoped`: For web applications, a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection).

[Detailed Microsoft docs on DI for dotnet here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

> It's important to note that EF uses a `scoped` lifetime by default.
> You can modify this behavior by overloading the `AddDbContext` call.

Regarding your question: the `scoped` lifetime is tied to a single web request, not a user session. Also, if you managed to somehow create a new instance of your `DbContext` with clean information, each new session would be creating a copy of the whole database in memory, which would very quickly become unmanageable.

Without knowing more about your application, a simple solution would be to tie the user's `sessionId` to a new column in each of your tables and use that as a discriminator when serving and modifying data.

That is, when a user opens the application, a new copy of your data is created with `{userSession}` added to a column in each of your entities. From that moment onwards, any request to the application will only touch the data assigned to that specific session.

This will make your DB grow quite quickly, but seeing as your working with an In-Memory DB, any time your AppService/Function is restarted you'll only be left with the original copy of the data as the DB is created.

You can also look into a more robust multi-tenancy implementation as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy).

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this is just for testing purposes, you can do something as follows:

I overridden `OnConfiguring` of `DataContext`, so every time a new `DataContext` is created it will connect to a different database name in memory using Guid as name.

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

using (var scope1 = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope1.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    dbContext.Users.Add(new User { Name = "John" });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("User names from scope 1: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dbContext.Users.Select(x => x.Name))); 
}

using (var scope2 = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope2.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    Console.WriteLine("User names from scope 2: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dbContext.Users.Select(x => x.Name)));
}


public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In my case it is for semi-production purposes. This means, that the DB for the main app is a simple SQL DB. However, for the "Demo App" we are planning, we want users to have the ability to try out the app in a sandbox environment. Each, independent of each oher and "clean" for each new session. I know, that this will use up some Memory, but we don't expect more than 50 sessions at once and our databas is relatively small.

Comment: Well in that case this approach might suffice your need, combining it with data seed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding